# Detect an iframe, server side (no javascript)?

Tags: html, iframe, server

How can I detect, server side, that my page is being loaded in an iframe?

Take a look at this HTML code - www.google.com refuses to load in an iframe. Other pages, like www.example.com do load in an iframe:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/" width="600" height="300"></iframe>
    </body>
 </html>
```

They don't use any JavaScript to detect it, so must be server side I guess? How is it made?

Answer (score 3):

Google sends a HTTP header `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` to prevent being shown in a IFrame. See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) for more information about the header.